# Initializing a list within ngOnInit using axios

Tags: typescript, axios, promise

I have a component in which I'd like to load objects received from the backend.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.source.load(this.myService.findAll());
    }
```

in myService, I use Axios to fetch the data from the backend. I can see that the data arrive to the frontend

```
public findAll(): any {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getAll')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

How to call the service from the component, so I would receive an array of objects?

Comment: You could return the promise from `findAll` and `await` it in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit is not async, so you will have to call your method in a fire-and-forget-way. Here is an answer using fetch, because i am not familiar with axios, but it is probably similiar.
You did not say which array you exactly expect. If you know it, you could replace `Promise<any>` with `Promise<MyObject[]>`. You may require `as MyObject[]` behind `.json()`

```
// angular component
ngOnInit() {
  (async () => {
    const data = await this.myService.findAll();
    this.source.load(data);
  })();
}

// MyService class
public async findAll(): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/getAll');
    if(!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("failed to fetch");      
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("failed to fetch");
  }
}
```